# Can't make DataGridView Checkbox non readonly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I'm binding a list to:

```
var list = GetOrderedPlayListItems(playList.Items.Where(f => f != null).ToList());
gvPlayListItems.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gvPlayListItems.DataSource = list;
Console.WriteLine(gvPlayListItems[3, 0].ReadOnly); //Displays TRUE
```

The problem I have is that my CheckBox column (column 4) is readonly. Things I've checked:

1. The designer for the column and the gridview are both readonly false.
2. I've checked my code and I'm not setting readonly anywhere.
3. I've checked `playList.Items` and the class behind that item has `public bool FullScreen {get;set;}` so nothing private and my `DataPropertyName` is FullScreen.

I've tried setting it to not readonly in bindcomplete but that didn't help.

Any ideas as I'm a little stumped and currently, can't click the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue for this. The column wasn't read only, the grid wasn't read only but after looking at my `Designer.cs` file and looking for `ReadOnly = true` I saw the `DataGridView.RowTemplate.ReadOnly` flag was set to true ...

I mean, how many read only's do we need :)

Anyway, that sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

what about gvPlayListItems[2, 0].ReadOnly? you mention the 3rd column but [3, 0] is the 4th column. Just a first glance look at the issue

Comment: Sorry just a typo. It's the fourth column, third index (note, I've done this using the column name as well with the same result to ensure it's looking at the correct column).